# Randomly select cells in df pandas

Tags: python, pandas

From this pandas df

```
1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1
```

samples_indices = df.sample(frac=0.5, replace=False).index
df.loc[samples_indices] = 'X'

will assign 'X' to all columns in randomly selected rows corresponding to 50% of df, like so:

```
X   X   X   X
1   1   1   1
X   X   X   X
1   1   1   1
```

But how do I assign 'X' to 50% randomly selected cells in the df?
For example like this:

```
X   X   X   1
1   X   1   1
X   X   X   1
1   1   1   X
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), for an efficient solution:

```
import numpy as np

df[np.random.choice([True, False], size=df.shape)] = 'X'

# with a custom probability:
N = 0.5
df[np.random.choice([True, False], size=df.shape, p=[N, 1-N])] = 'X'
```

Example output:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  X  1  X  X
1  X  X  1  X
2  X  X  X  1
3  X  X  1  X
```

If you need an exact proportion, you can use:

```
frac = 0.5
df[np.random.permutation(df.size).reshape(df.shape)>=df.size*frac] = 'X'
```

Example:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  X  1  X  1
1  X  1  X  1
2  1  1  X  1
3  X  X  1  X
```

Answer (score 3):

Create `MultiIndex Series` by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then use [`Series.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sample.html) and last replace removed values by `X` in [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
N = 0.5
df = (df.stack().sample(frac=1-N).unstack(fill_value='X')
         .reindex(index=df.index, columns=df.columns, fill_value='X'))
print (df)
   0  1  2  3
0  X  X  1  1
1  X  1  X  1
2  1  X  X  X
3  1  1  1  X
```

Comment: Love this answer!! Just I don't understand why this approach is not setting to 'X' the exact specific fraction of cells (50% in this case).

Comment: @RiccardoBucco except it gives incorrect results, it can incorrectly drop rows/columns if by chance a combination is not selected. try to set a low `frac` (e.g. with `N=0.99`) ;)

Comment: A workaround to fix it would be to add `.reindex_like(df).fillna('X')`, but I prefer a numpy approach

Comment: @mozway - added `reindex` for avoid it

Answer (score 3):

In @mozway's answer you can set to 'X' cells with a certain probability. But let's say you want to have exactly 50% of your data being marked as 'X'. This is how you can do it:

```
import numpy as np

df[np.random.permutation(np.hstack([np.ones(df.size // 2), np.zeros(df.size // 2)])).astype(bool).reshape(df.shape)] = 'X'
```

Example output:

```
X   X   X   1
1   X   1   1
X   X   X   1
1   1   1   X
```